# Which is the best translation of the Upanishads in English?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, book-recommendation

I'm currently studying a course on Hindu scriptures and would love to read the Upanishads.  Please can someone guide me to the best translation there is available.

Many Thanks !

Comment: I can recommend you Swami Madhavananda’s translation of one particular important Upanishad: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad

Comment: Thank you ! I'll definitely have a look.  So far I've read Easwaran's translation, ut I'm told it misses some details.  Unsure if this is accurate.

Comment: You are welcome. Also have a look at Mahadeva Sastri’s English translation of the Taittiriya Upanishad: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad. Both links include Shankaracharya’s commentary.

Comment: Which is the best is subjective. @EktaSrivastav

Answer (score 1):

[The Principles of Upanishad](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://archive.org/details/PrincipalUpanishads&ved=2ahUKEwijyL-Gwv7oAhVEAXIKHcIMDdcQFjAWegQIDBAB&usg=AOvVaw07TSWBIgJXdcjQAj2TiSB6&cshid=1587643851995) by Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan.

Or you can also download [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bhartiyadarshan.upanishad) to read Upanishad offline.