# Good translation of the Upanishads?

Tags: upanishads

Can anyone recommend a good translation of the principal Upanishads, preferably a book I can order.
Thanks.

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with your question since what is "good" is subjective, it makes your question "opinion based".

Comment: @Rickross Should I answer it, or shall that be flagged?

Comment: this is duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40113/12304 and also opinion based...

Comment: Not a duplicate, since I'm looking for a book rather than an online reference. And most of the content here is "opinion based", since references are chosen selectively to support opinions. Why is this site such hard work? <sigh>

Comment: @WillyWonka Hi! I personally study the commentary of Chinmayananda and Tejomayananda, may be you'll enjoy them too.

Comment: The Eight Upanishads vol 1&2 by Gambiranandha, mostly with comments from Adishankara  is good. 
In this there is translation, transliteration and commentary which you can ignore if you want

Answer (score 2):

An excellent translation is by the combined efforts of the Irish poet Yeats and Sri Swami Purohit. It's called *The Ten Principal Upanishads*.

In fact Yeats relates that he was moved to make the translation after hearing great things about the Upanishads from his Indian friends but when leafing through the then translations available in English, he thought that if what they said was true, then the beauty of the original hadn't come through. Hence the combined effort by Sri Swami Purohit.

It's also a short book. Out of the 103 canonical Upanishads, the ten principals ones are:

> 1. Isha
> 2. Kena
> 3. Katha
> 4. Prashan
> 5. Mundaka
> 6. Mandukya
> 7. Tattireya
> 8. Aitareya
> 9. Chhandoghya
> 10. Brihadaranyaka

In toto, about a hundred and fifty pages as I recall and was first published in 1938.

Comment: Thanks, that one looks interesting, so I have ordered a paperback copy. I already have the Wordsworth Classics translation, but would like another translation to compare it to.

Answer (score 1):

The Principal Upanishads by S.Radhakrishnan is a reasonable book.
The Upanishads by Swami Nikhilananda is also good.